# Retrieving series rows given a condition

Tags: python, pandas, series

Consider the following series which represents the distance between location `a` and locations `b`, `c`, `d`:

```
   a   
a  0

b  10

c  12

d  21
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is retrieve all location names that are within a certain distance from `a`.

For example, I would like to print out all variables that are within a 15 unit distance from `a`, excluding `a`, which would be `b` and `c`.

> b
>
> c

I've tried creating an empty list and then using a for loop to append to that list but to no avail, so I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Absolute distance or signed distance, in case that matters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: @timgeb thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the post. There are no negative values so it does not matter.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it's helpful but does not really answer my question no. I had already managed to retrieve the rows but I'm trying to print the row names that satisfy the condition.

Comment: @grimrol123 Is it a series or dataframe?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it is a series

Comment: @grimrol123 Can you include a snippet of code showing what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dist = 15
val = list(df.loc[(df['a'] < dist) & (df.index != 'a')].index)
print(val)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget loops, pandas and numpy already have builtin functions that make the job. In this case you can use np.where.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.Series({'a':0, 'b':10, 'c':12, 'd':21}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.iloc[np.where((df<=15) & (df.index !='a'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, i assumed the first column is an index:

```
print(df[(df['a'] < 15) & (df.index != 'a')])

      a
loc
b    10
c    12
```